# results of divide and conquer algorithm randomly change to zeros

Tags: c, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have written a program for an algorithms class which takes integer arrays as an argument and finds the subarray with its sum being closest to zero. The program compiles and runs. The results are correct most of the time it's ran, but seemingly randomly it will print zeros for the subarray's sum and indices values. The sets of data which print the zero's for their results are always the same sets when the error does occur. I can't figure out why this would happen, maybe a memory issue of some kind. It would make sense if the results were always incorrect or correct, but, since no variables are changing, I am stumped. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Numbers
{
    int num;
    int index;
};
struct Sums
{
    int sum;
    int indice_i;
    int indice_j;
} ClosestToZero_default={INT_MAX,INT_MAX,INT_MAX};

typedef struct Sums ClosestToZero;

int struct_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    struct Numbers *ia=(struct Numbers*)a;  // magic 
    struct Numbers *ib=(struct Numbers*)b;
    return (int)(ia->num-ib->num); 
}
void print_result(int result,int indice_i,int indice_j)
{
    printf("Sum of Subarray Closest to Zero: %d\nStart Index: %d  End Index: %d\n\n",result,indice_i,indice_j);
}
struct Sums findMiddle(struct Numbers* array,int start_index,int end_index)
{
    ClosestToZero result=ClosestToZero_default;

    int i,j;
    int n=end_index-start_index+1;
    int size_left=(n+1)/2;      
    int size_right=n-size_left;

    struct Numbers left_array[size_left];
    struct Numbers right_array[size_right];

    int sum=0; 
    j=size_left-1;
    for(i=start_index+size_left-1;i>=start_index;i--,j--)
    {
        left_array[j]=array[i];
        left_array[j].num+=sum;
        sum+=array[i].num;
    }
    sum=0;
    j=start_index+size_left;
    for(i=0;i<size_right;i++,j++)
    {
        right_array[i]=array[j];
        right_array[i].num+=sum;
        sum+=array[j].num;
    }
    qsort(left_array,size_left,sizeof(struct Numbers),struct_cmp);
    qsort(right_array,size_right,sizeof(struct Numbers),struct_cmp);

    i=0;
    j=size_right-1;
    while(1)
    {
        if(left_array[i].num>0||right_array[j].num<0) break;
        if(abs(left_array[i].num+right_array[j].num)<result.sum)
        {
            result.sum=abs(left_array[i].num+right_array[j].num);
            result.indice_i=left_array[i].index;
            result.indice_j=right_array[j].index;
        }
        if(abs(left_array[i].num)>abs(right_array[j].num)) i++;
        else j--;
    }
    while(i<size_left&&j>=0)
    {
        if(left_array[i].num<0) 
        {
            i++; 
            continue;
        }
        if(right_array[j].num>0) 
        {
            j--; 
            continue;
        }
        if(abs(left_array[i].num+right_array[j].num)<result.sum)
        {
            result.sum=abs(left_array[i].num+right_array[j].num);
            result.indice_i=left_array[i].index;
            result.indice_j=right_array[j].index;
        }
        if(abs(left_array[i].num)>abs(right_array[j].num)) j--;
        else i++;       
    }
    return result;
}
struct Sums algorithm2(struct Numbers* array,int start_index,int end_index)
{
    int i,j;
    ClosestToZero result_left;
    ClosestToZero result_right;
    ClosestToZero result_mid;


    if(end_index==start_index)
    {
        result_mid.sum=abs(array[start_index].num);
        result_mid.indice_i=result_mid.indice_j=array[start_index].index;
        return result_mid;
    }
    if(end_index-start_index==1)
    {
        int a=abs(array[start_index].num);
        int b=abs(array[end_index].num);
        int c=abs(array[start_index].num+array[end_index].num);

        if(a<b&&a<c)
        {
            result_mid.sum=a;
            result_mid.indice_i=result_mid.indice_j=array[start_index].index;
        }
        else if(b<a&&b<c)
        {
            result_mid.sum=b;
            result_mid.indice_i=result_mid.indice_j=array[end_index].index;
        }
        else
        {
            result_mid.sum=c;
            result_mid.indice_i=array[start_index].index;
            result_mid.indice_j=array[end_index].index;
        }
        return result_mid;
    }
    int mid_index=(start_index+end_index)/2;
    result_left=algorithm2(array,start_index,mid_index);
    result_right=algorithm2(array,mid_index+1,end_index);
    result_mid=findMiddle(array,start_index,end_index);

    if(result_left.sum<result_right.sum&&result_left.sum<result_mid.sum)
        return result_left;
    if(result_right.sum<result_left.sum&&result_right.sum<result_mid.sum)
        return result_right;
    return result_mid;
}
int closestZeroSum(int* arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    struct Numbers array[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        array[i].num=arr[i];
        array[i].index=i;
    }
    struct Sums result=algorithm2(array,0,n-1); 
    print_result(result.sum,result.indice_i,result.indice_j);

    return 0;
}
int main(int argc,int argv[])
{
    int arr1[]={499228, 21572, -323857, 288186, -451707, -228193, -443913, -313419, 236065, -52692, 42198, -169000, 418130, 246890, 16091, 201633, 124538, 418432, -385986, 154610, 85740, 211439, -169332, 104064, 162438, 251, -179159, 136801, -187420, 189088, 67512, -74248, -150024, -467850, -235169, 214345, 455041, 453804, -467983, -56033, 479772, 494760, -168594, 10655, 437440, 157697, 407151, 466806, -168368, 74531, 214696, -35099, -344876, -377398, -392111, 236400, 93324, 155484, -110424, 440427, -220568, -147152, -330916, 419883, 332187, 314146, 379534, -351921, -374375, 301787, -18693, -88397, 68640, -90075, -165441, 7676, -49795, -358864, 110334, 3909, 51923, -350801, 211367, 178221, -48033, 173907, 137308, 454152, 334786, 247404, 261047, 122729, -439424, -318938, -367503, 379156, -170671, -154459, -395737, -193401}; 
    int arr1_size=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);

    int arr2[]={386521, -426105, -51327, -479314, 266939, -483585, 5174, -26325, -174507, 420884, 16180, 349704, 60431, -345921, 402022, 139333, -132008, 72744, -102568, -46460, 450996, -371577, -488895, 58007, -235653, 297566, -325213, -257872, 93030, 3737, -166953, -32082, -149683, -359092, -414417, 78794, 61943, 223186, 79294, -170009, -32876, 412168, -199555, 488317, 432080, 448046, 98065, 304298, -183989, -72475, -148109, 397536, 482222, 374665, -389837, -220047, -474078, -345931, -180385, -136260, 427174, 417819, 318218, 83008, 239618, 496199, 195442, -346491, -182687, -12742, -315836, 129197, -165305, 13224, -63483, 461599, 118305, -136678, 252502, 304408, 192900, -384603, -49832, -225063, -388805, 30286, -58632, 224370, -212093, -214778, 227535, -263757, 430684, 318599, 21355, 52281, -73725, -486957, -118220, 62683}; 
    int arr2_size=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int);

    int arr3[]={258821, 306066, -231500, -436295, 306425, 241361, 68153, 216106, -353968, 425757, 438111, -65653, -90992, -408188, -319437, 151786, -356247, -424078, -230531, 51863, 371945, 439278, -98784, 445010, -8235, 177337, 123174, 375508, -308068, 420045, 410467, 344006, 272623, 226552, -198151, -38586, 233206, -479137, -64701, -185958, 17319, 9237, -451752, 28414, 45946, -99873, -451984, 325519, -372670, 330385, 26093, 331932, 66849, -346808, 105535, 313619, -437154, 489421, -294743, -82994, -328806, 425808, -4951, 380292, -284245, -263289, 99328, -136943, 334475, -488275, 45777, 462572, -105101, -268580, 445742, 228270, -386481, -311534, -493956, -465020, 414547, -407161, 62069, -258371, 442358, 170609, -337386, 316532, -247616, 281311, -327522, -472093, -418488, 45369, -122124, 356880, 392005, -228005, -404684, -315306}; 
    int arr3_size=sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(int);

    int arr4[]={-214717, 361303, 416397, -60197, 324864, -330864, 269005, 24278, -212135, 328504, 444353, -286586, 168424, -101904, -316543, -423435, -255180, 287940, 445395, 115632, -253558, 147979, -152719, 365455, -495117, -276957, -198353, 407462, 72712, -363120, -290174, -21743, -273045, 447738, -391003, 322787, 130778, 266059, -215648, 335540, 379559, -409427, -434836, -326577, -56499, 299815, 154620, 407297, -481496, 59677, 229793, 495171, 498055, -339219, 271951, 487629, -396570, -424726, 309446, 320962, 362817, -89534, 82070, 146429, -145523, 356977, 286852, -436864, 237388, -211029, 395540, 330818, 299266, 453390, -184790, 187741, -242354, -151414, -416877, 384540, 341533, 415449, 294444, 257065, 230018, 240416, -317276, -306150, -162259, -135509, -32091, 77089, -231556, -134644, 11163, 320983, 443832, -393703, -384938, -20882}; 
    int arr4_size=sizeof(arr4)/sizeof(int);

    int arr5[]={-210333, -203574, -29420, -375363, -393800, 421046, -244507, 354795, -489162, 163316, 108146, -130364, 189343, -265580, -104608, -354593, -196407, -83326, -259045, 91954, 102741, -374334, -195592, -328131, -128635, -145780, -268674, -206437, 168629, -496691, 83207, 464554, -184084, -409403, -445299, 41312, 234004, -459966, -127733, -427338, -311021, -449664, 85188, -482381, -21829, -381143, -158807, -317729, -181146, 102318, -112927, 493008, 333608, 187402, -201813, 288212, -262296, -306723, -220246, 479108, 415186, -372438, -246269, -353105, 333361, 394104, 482347, -23831, 168611, -207283, 38343, 314168, -281553, 281228, -474763, 332710, -198532, 321268, -344461, 483687, 31910, 90240, 435233, 466993, -389003, 67743, 454699, 76577, 204593, 13466, 362508, -68273, -187942, -363061, -485642, 409273, 285247, 411904, 80985, 324690}; 
    int arr5_size=sizeof(arr5)/sizeof(int);

    int arr6[]={368944, 321652, -362363, -234897, 105687, 65523, -404365, 176408, 182830, 338002, -290518, 166771, -365419, -271724, -127480, -322735, -378171, -39266, -435294, 476897, 499179, 157601, 198607, 491320, -389158, -303347, -472691, 100100, -14174, -29001, 421124, 270487, -376761, 481298, 36273, 459798, 358359, -63152, -206361, 117190, 185374, 41951, -124229, -73667, -214465, -182715,-215614, -476948, 315622, 64995, 497534, -12914, 415459, -52916, 460256, 400891, 183325, 429259, -153934, -180787, -21403, -193158, 272599, -136778, -368140, -279420, -250377, -220183, -439302, 464769, 214400, -120020, 374103, 128886, 381712, -3005, 487535, 39729, 148154, 446269, -312541, -78711, 97321, 152678, -438171, 60025, -390485, -363629, 17071, 356450, -189293, -157489, -146602, -219611, 427199, -446551, -490620, 325541, 210627, 384613};
    int arr6_size=sizeof(arr6)/sizeof(int);


    printf("\n\nExpected Output is: 251, 25, 25\n");
    printf("algorithm2--------------------------\n");
    closestZeroSum(arr1,arr1_size);

    printf("Expected Output is: 89, 94, 96\n");
    printf("algorithm2--------------------------\n");
    closestZeroSum(arr2,arr2_size);

    printf("Expected Output is: 3, 3, 96\n");
    printf("algorithm2--------------------------\n");
    closestZeroSum(arr3,arr3_size);

    printf("Expected Output is: 576, 3, 47\n");
    printf("algorithm2--------------------------\n");
    closestZeroSum(arr4,arr4_size);

    printf("Expected Output is: 325, 72, 73\n");
    printf("algorithm2--------------------------\n");
    closestZeroSum(arr5,arr5_size);

    printf("Expected Output is: 271, 68, 96\n");
    printf("algorithm2--------------------------\n");
    closestZeroSum(arr6,arr6_size);

    return 0;
}
```

I have some testing and have found some interesting results; I can't make sense of them though. When I put print statements in base cases for the result_mid.num value prior to it being returned, I received a segmentation fault. I also added an extra base case for when there were only 3 elements left to compare. With the set of test data I have posted, this will work, but with the actual data, which is a must larger set, I still get the same type of error. This time the error occurs in sets of data which previously were always correct.

> Why might the results of some sets of data randomly, and incorrectly, produce zeros?

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hopefully true code does not use/need bad main parameter `int argv[]`.

Comment: The true code does indeed not use/need bad main parameter int argv[].

Comment: 1) show sample inputs that work 2) show sample input that do not work 3) show actual output from input sample that works  4) show expected output and actual output for sample input that does not work.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: regarding lines like: `if(end_index-start_index==1)`  the C operator precedence will save you, but for readability the line would be better written as: `if( (end_index-start_index) == 1)`  Note: appropriate horizontal spacing greatly enhances readability.

Comment: Please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ) )  The compiler will output several warning messages, including: unused parameter: 'argc'  unused parameter: 'argv'.  Both can be fixed by changing the main() signature to `int main( void )`

Comment: for the function: `qsort()` please read the man page.  Notice that certain of the parameters are expected to be of type: `size_t`, but the posted code is passing a parameter of type `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random data is a good hint that array access is out-of-bounds.

Algorithmic error leads to access of `right_array[-1]`

```
  while (1) {
    if (!(j >= 0 && j < size_right)) {
      printf("!1 %d %d\n", j, size_right);
      exit(0);
    }
    if (!(i >= 0 && j < size_left)) {
      printf("!2 %d %d\n", j, size_left);
      exit(0);
    }
    if (left_array[i].num > 0 || right_array[j].num < 0) break;
```

Outputs

```
Expected Output is: 251, 25, 25
algorithm2--------------------------
!1 -1 1
```

Suspect `while (1)` should be
 `while (j >= 0)`

---

Other minor issues.

`struct_cmp()`

```
// return (int) (ia->num - ib->num);
return  (ia->num - ib->num) - (ia->num < ib->num);
```

`size_t` for array indexes.  `INT_MAX` --> `SIZE_MAX` for index types.

`abs(int + int)` a problem in 2 ways: sum overflow and `INT_MIN`

Overall, code would benefit with *some* comments.

Comment: That was the correct reason. Thank you very much and I apologize for the lack of commenting.  I simply replaced the `while(1)` with `while(i < size_left - 1 && j >= 0)` to keep the indexes in bounds.